# Cómo aplicar un filtro por fecha en sqlite

Tags: sqlite

estoy haciendo una aplicación que tiene que traer todos los datos de un mes (que elije el usuario) y no estoy seguro si lo que estoy haciendo es correcto. Por ejemplo, para traer todos los datos de una base de piezas que hayan sido cargados en enero de este año mi consulta luce de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT * FROM basePiezas WHERE fechaCargado > "2019-01" AND fechaCargado < "2019-02"
```

Vale aclarar que "fechaCargado" es un campo del tipo DATE y se guardan elementos del estilo "2019-03-24 19:45:53".

Vale aclarar que en mis pruebas funciona, pero a lo mejor no estoy considerando algún caso.

Comment: no veo ningún problema en la consulta, si buscas otra alternativa a < y > puedes usar `between`.

Comment: ¿qué ventajas me trae el between? claramente una de ellas es que mi query sería más compacta, ¿pero hay otras?

Comment: creo que no existen otras ventajas, pero la diferencia es que `between` es un operador inclusivo, es decir `fechaCargado between "2019-01" AND  "2019-02"` es lo mismo que `fechaCargado => "2019-01" AND fechaCargado <= "2019-02"`, incluye también los limites.

Comment: Entiendo, pero eso haría que si sólo guardo el mes y el año también me traiga las cosas de febrero, no?

Comment: si, aunque no se si el primero te trae los datos desde el 02 de enero en lugar de 01, en ese caso puedes poner `fechaCargado => "2019-01" AND fechaCargado < "2019-02"`

Comment: claro, pero por lo que tengo entendido el "2019-01" es menor que "2019-01-01" por lo tanto tendría que traerlo